# java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?autoReconnectForPools=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc

I run a web application on tomcat 7. My Web application use connector mysql to connect db. It connect to mysql and query ok. But when I run it for 3 - 4 hours it occur error with get connection and the log I get in tomcat is

> "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for
>   jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?autoReconnectForPools=true&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf-8
>   at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)   at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)"

Comment: do `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` before you start your connection

Comment: Do you have the jar in your classpath?

Comment: Of Course I have use this comment.I have add in tomcat lib. note that it run ok the first after for along time it occur exception. I think may be tomcat leak memory and restrict register mysql driver.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably [a result of Tomcat service provider mechanism memory leaks prevention efforts.](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html#DriverManager,_the_service_provider_mechanism_and_memory_leaks) A workaround suggested is to register the driver manually in your controller:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing the jar with the MySQL driver. If it's not under /WEB-INF/lib then drop it in /lib/ext

Comment: Don't drop it in `lib\ext`; it is deprecated and will be removed in future Java versions. Instead drop it in the tomcat lib folder.

Comment: I have add in tomcat lib. note that it run ok the first after for along time it occur exception. I think may be tomcat leak memory and restrict register mysql driver.

Comment: Can you explain better? You put the jar in the lib folder, start the application and it's able of getting connections to the database until certain point in which you get an exception? The same as in your question or a different one?

Comment: Yes. It will exception after run for a time.